# using date range with mongoexport command

Tags: mongodb, mongoexport

In my mongo database I have the data in this format

```
{ "_id" : { "$oid" : "53179b7f036457ea7fff00a7" }, "act" : "browserInfo", "creAt" : { "$date" : "2014-03-05T16:47:43.845-0500" }}
```

I'm trying to come up with a shell script that would export the entries with a given date range using the below script(I named it csv_from_mongo_collection.sh)

```
#!/bin/bash
db_name=$1
collection=$2
output_file=$3

for i in "$@"
do
case $i in
    --from=*)
    from="${i#*=}"
    shift
    ;;
    --to=*)
    to="${i#*=}"
    shift
    ;;
esac
done

query="{creAt:{$gte:new Date($from),$lt:new Date($to)}}";

mongoexport --db "$db_name" --collection "$collection" --out "$output_file" --query "$query"
```

When I run the below command I see that all the entries from that specified collection are uploaded ignoring the date range I have set.

```
csv_from_mongo_collection.sh mydb analytics analytics_content.json --from=01/01/2013 --to=12/01/2013
```

Can someone help fix my script/command? Thank you

Answer (score 0):

The issue is on `query="{creAt:{$gte:new Date($from),$lt:new Date($to)}}";`

How `$gte` and `$lt` will be treated? As variables undefined? ($from is defined) :)

`new Date("01/01/2013")` is correct but not `new Date(01/01/2013)`

Use single quote `'` to produce the query document as you want.

Comment: Thank you. I think that solved the query construction problem. Now mongoexport fails to understand the query.                                      assertion: 16619 code FailedToParse: FailedToParse: First character in field must be [A-Za-z$_]: offset:8 of:{creAt:{:new Date('01/01/2013'),:new Date('12/01/2013')}}

Comment: @Srini Kandula, Problem is still on the query construction, because `$gte` and `$lt` have been resolved as variables with empty string.

Answer (score 0):

By using double quotes (`"`) to create your query, all words in the query string prefixed with `$` will be evaluated as variables. Because `$word` is a bash variable.
I marked all variables in your query string:

```sh
query="{creAt:{$gte:new Date($from),$lt:new Date($to)}}";
               ^^^^          ^^^^^  ^^^          ^^^
```

As you can see not only `$from` and `$to` are variables, but `$gte` and `$lt` are also evaluated as variables! Then how do you store your dates in the string whilst also conforming to the query syntax?

Use the escape character `\` to escape the `\$` in your query string. Now to `$` sign wont be evaluated as the usage of a variable! Example below.

```sh
query="{creAt:{\$gte:new Date($from),\$lt:new Date($to)}}";
```